# How to generate object ids when $unwinding with aggregate in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I'm having the following query

```
db.getCollection('matches').aggregate([{
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "player",
      "localField": "players.account_id",
      "foreignField": "account_id",
      "as": "players2"
    }
  }, {
    "$addFields": {
      "players": {
        "$map": {
          "input": "$players",
          "in": {
            "$mergeObjects": [
              "$$this", {
                "$arrayElemAt": [
                  "$players2", {
                    "$indexOfArray": [
                      "$players.account_id",
                      "$$this.account_id"
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }, {
    "$set": {
      "players.match_id": "$match_id",
      "players.radiant_win": "$radiant_win"
    }
  }, {
    "$unwind": "$players"
  }, {
    "$replaceRoot": {
      "newRoot": "$players"
    }
  }, {
      "$project": {
        "_id": 1,
        "match_id": 1,
        "account_id": 1,
        "hero_id": 1,
        "radiant_win": 1
       }
    }
])
```

which is supposed to match an inner array with another collection, merge the objects in the arrays by the matching and then unwrap ($unwind) the array into a new collection.

Unfortunately, I'm getting duplicate Object ids which is sort of a problem for when I want to export this collection.

How can I ensure unique Object_Ids for the aggregation?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you can ignore `"_id": 0,` and when you export the data it will be without `_id`, when you import into the collection new object will be created. .. Do you think still, you need `_id`?

Comment: you are right, I might not need it at all. Will try now, thank you!